# Delete current node in recursive ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Considering the following situation:

http://jsfiddle.net/dzpGY/1/

How would I delete a specific node, instead of deleting child nodes from the parent. Use of `data.$parent` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/dzpGY/

You were close, it is `$parent.data.nodes` but, you can not put that into `$scope.delete` since this methods `$scope` would refer to the tree's root `$scope`, and you want to refer to the leafs parent.

You can create a separate `controller` for each leaf of `ng-repeat` and put a `delete()` method there.

Comment: I suppose that fiddle was mis-leading, check out this one http://jsfiddle.net/dzpGY/1/ , i want to be able to use 'Delete this node'

Comment: Hmmm, where is says "Delete This Node", I want to be able to click that and delete the node i'm currently on. I'm not sure what you intended your fiddle to do, but it is not doing that. The effort however is much appreciated.